# Google Apps Script JSON element to Float

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using the following script on Google Apps Script to retrieve the value of my Helium wallet:

```
function getBalance() {
  try {
    var url = 'https://api.helium.io/v1/accounts/1451THihiR9hDzkgdn4ZMSTzC8cuQJh9StXJGVPEcTPEXjKzjdH'
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    var balance = data.data.balance;
    var myTime = new Date();
    Logger.log(balance);
    Logger.log(myTime);
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log(data)
    Logger.log(err.message);
  }
}
```

My issue is that the number that is returned as `balance` is:

```
9:26:42 PM  Info  5.08178108E8
```

The balance is actually `5.08178108`. I want to convert the element into a Float but I can't find a way to do that. Converting it to a string removes the decimal. How do I convert the balance into a Float while retaining the decimal position?

Comment: About `The balance is actually 5.08178108.`, from `9:26:42 PM  Info  5.08178108E8`, in your situation, I thought that the value might be `508178108`. How about this?

Comment: The value from curl is 508178108 but UrlFetchApp is adding the decimal place. I actually want the decimal place because I don't have 508178108 HNT - I have 5.08178108 HNT.

Comment: Its actually in scientific notation if you want 5.08... divide by 1E8

Comment: Thank you for replying. `5.08178108E8` is the exponential notation. So this value is the same with `508178108`. And, in this case, `Logger.log` is used, such situation occurs. If you want to see the value as `508178108`, please modify `Logger.log(balance)` to `console.log(balance)`. By this, you can see `508178108` at the log.

Comment: How do I divide by 1E8?

Comment: In that case, how about `console.log(balance / 1E8)` or `var balance = data.data.balance / 1E8`?

Comment: 5.08178108E8 is scientific notation which means 5.08178108*10^8 (10 to the 8th power)

Comment: That did it `var balance = data.data.balance / 1E8;`. Thanks @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) for this answer:

I ended up converting the balance into a Float by dividing by `1E8`. Here's the entire function:

```
function getBalance() {
  try {
    var url = 'https://api.helium.io/v1/accounts/1451THihiR9hDzkgdn4ZMSTzC8cuQJh9StXJGVPEcTPEXjKzjdH'
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    var balance = data.data.balance / 1E8;
    var myTime = new Date();
    Logger.log(balance);
    Logger.log(myTime);
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log(data)
    Logger.log(err.message);
  }
}
```

This allowed me to set the value in my Google Sheet and make calculations off of it.